# .htaccess redirect. Wp network login page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

.htaccess

I have wp network:

1. site.com
2. a.site.com
3. b.site.com
4. login.site.com

How can I make redirect for all */wp-login.php (domain and subdomains) to login.site.com/wp-login.php and except login.site.com/wp-login.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule **on the top of other rules**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^login\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(wp-login\.php)$ http://login.site.com/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you.